# MalformedResponse expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: at most two 'simple_responses' are supported

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

> MalformedResponse
>   expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: at most two 'simple_responses' are supported.

This error comes on welcome intent. How to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Only send two simple responses, at most.

If you're using the actions-on-google library, this means you only call `conv.ask()` with a text string twice in a response. If you're using the dialogflow-fulfillment library, you can only call `agent.add()` with a text string twice.

One way around this is to build the string you want to send as a response before you call `conv.ask()` or `agent.add()`. This way you're sending back just one simple response, even if it contains additional information. There is a 640 character limit on each string sent.

In general - you shouldn't need more than one response. You can say a lot with 640 characters! Having two is to allow for multiple chat bubbles in visual responses where it might make sense (for example, if you wanted to send a reply in one, and prompt something else in the next). Allowing longer than this probably means your response is too long, which can be unpleasant for a spoken conversational design. How long do you listen to someone before you tune them out?

Comment: So to 'reset' the simple response limit, a new intent needs to be called?I am making a game which has a lot of audio files, for example after a given intent is triggered there might be a sting sound , followed by an asisstant speech, followed by another sting sound.

Is there a way around this apart from concatenating audio files?

Also out of interest do you know why this limitation is set? Cheers!

Comment: Yes, but if you're sending audio through SSML, you can include the audio and what the user is saying in a single simple SSML message. This is allowed to go past the 640 character limit.